# Search Results by specified site

Tags: bing-search

I'm wondering if there is a way to limit the Bing Web Search API to return only results for a specific website. I'm migrating from Google Custom Search to Bing Web Search API. I would like to limit all search queries to the website URL.

If I search for cars on the coolcars.com site it only returns results for coolcars.com and not anothersite.com.

Here's a link to the Bing Web Search API: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-web-search-api/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass the website in as part of the query using `site:`. Per Microsoft's [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v7-reference):

> The query string may contain Bing Advanced Operators. For example, to
>   limit results to a specific domain, use the `site:` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Bing custom search for this (at https://www.customsearch.ai/). It is meant for limiting search results to specific domains/webpages.

Answer (score -2):

A next Q: how to include subdomains in the search?
Example:
site:startpagina.nl "coaching" -prikbord
should give back subdomains like: (in Google search)

`http://coaching.startpagina.nl/

http://coaching-counselling.startpagina.nl/

http://wandelcoach.startpagina.nl/`

but it only gives back www. results like:
`https://www.startpagina.nl
https://www.startpagina.nl/v/maatschappij/onderwijs/vraag/371779/
https://www.startpagina.nl/v/financien-werk/carriere-werk/vraag/`

Comment: You'd probably be better served to ask this question as a question rather than an answer to the original question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask